# Reading file from remote server using groovy

Tags: groovy, compiler-errors, sftp, remote-access, datainputstream

I am trying to read a specific entry in a file on a remote Linux server,  I have no idea how to do it, i searched around and below is what i am trying but it doesnt work and throwing exceptions

Below is the exception i get , Can some one also confirm if the above code is OK?

```
 latest.groovy: 50: expecting EOF, found 'in' @ line 50, column 17.
 DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(io)
               ^

 1 error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in` is a keyword in groovy.

Change the variable name to something else...

Maybe `dataInputStream` ?

You can find a list of the keywords here http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_keywords

Comment: I changed and i get the below exception

Comment: Caught: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '/atthome/att/ccatt/mb_ccatt/temp/cllist_latest.groovy' Invalid index
BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '/atthome/att/ccatt/mb_ccatt/temp/cllist_latest.groovy' Invalid index
Caused by: sun.misc.InvalidJarIndexException: Invalid index

Comment: I figured it out. Its some of import statements causing the issue